# Why does my code seem to stop at Interaction.editReply()?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was making a game command in discord.js, but when attempting to `editReply`, it won't go past that... I tried putting console logs before and after, and the one after didn't run. I tried using `await interaction.deferReply()`, and that just stayed on `BotName is thinking...`. The arguments are passed in correctly and there aren't any errors.

Here is the code:

```js
async execute(client, interaction, args) {
    await interaction.reply(`valid string here`) // does send
    let num = Math.floor((Math.random() * (args[0] || 1000)) + 1); //get random number
    let guesses = 0;
    let logs = ["None"];
    console.log("Running 1") // logs
    await interaction.editReply(
      `valid string here`
    )
    console.log("Running 2") // doesn't log and doesn't edit
    // ...
}
```

After using `client.on("debug")` and `client.on("warn")`, it seems I'm getting a 429, but I'm not even looping, and it was working just fine yesterday

```
Hit a 429 while executing a request.
    Global  : false
    Method  : patch
    Path    : /webhooks/---/messages/@original
    Route   : /webhooks/:id/---/messages/@original
    Limit   : Infinity
    Timeout : 500ms
    Sublimit: 1130000ms
```

Comment: I put the exact code you provided into my bot, tested it, and it works perfectly fine. Both logs send, and the edit works perfectly. I'm not sure what is causing this issue for you. Are you sure this isn't caused by some other simple mistake, like not saving the file?

Comment: Well, it's on replit, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Perhaps that is the problem. I know in the past, when working with Java on replit, sometimes the saving would get wonky. I'd make very simple changes to the code (such as adding a `System.out.println("hello world")`) that should be working perfectly, but when running the repl it would act as if I had never made those changes. After refreshing the page a few times, the changes I added would then disappear as if they had not been saved. That certainly caused a ton of confusion for me when trying to debug code on replit. Perhaps that's the issue you're having? If not, I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Weird... all my `.editReply`s aren't working anymore... I used a command that worked yesterday that edits the reply, but it didn't

Comment: Logging the method gives the correct value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new edit to the question most likely answers your question. If you host a bot on replit (especially with free hosting), it is likely that your bot will share an IP with other bots hosted on replit. Discord's rate limits are enforced based on the IP that is requesting the API. All it takes for this error to occur is for someone else on replit (whose bot happens to share the same IP as yours) to create a poorly/maliciously designed discord bot that spams the API and causes your bot's IP to get rate limited. In this case, I assume someone was using `.editReply()` too much in a poorly designed loop or such.

As for a solution to this issue, I found this [replit post](https://replit.com/talk/ask/Discord-Bot-How-to-fix-429-rate-limit-error/121289). It suggests that you can "run `kill 1` in the shell tab to destroy the current container and switch to a new one." That post is from 10 months ago, so it may or may not work now. (If this doesn't work, an alternate solution could also be to fork your own repl, and then delete the original. This may also switch your bot over to a new IP).