# Discord.js client doesn't work and doesn't give any errors

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, client

So my discord bot that I host on repl.it for free (so that might be the problem) works fine most of the time but sometimes, it will just randomly stop working. Even when I restart it, the client.on("ready") function won't trigger and nothing works. This problem just fixes it self after some time but it is really anoying and it keeps happening. It has nothing to do with my code as it works and there is nothing chance based in my code that may break it, and even then it would trow an error, this just doesn't work and doesn't give any errors. If you would like to take a look at my code it is on repl.it [here](https://replit.com/@farima4/anonymous-message#index.js). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, the problem is Replit. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70311641/6901876). This question isn't necessarily a duplicate of that one, but the reason behind the error in that question is essentially the same as the reason behind your issue. The solutions I included in that answer may also solve this problem for you.

Comment: @Cannicide thanks on the info. The bot is back and working for now but I will try it out when it stops again.

Answer (score 0):

Replit is a free hosting platform but if I remember well, if no one get into the page for a certain time, the program will stop. It is probably that that stops your bot.

(sorry if you don't understand well my English)

Comment: I made a webserver using express and ping it with uptime robot every 10 minutes so the bot doesn't shut down. I know what the problem was. People with the same ip as me were requesting too much stuff from discord so both me and them got rate limited. Thanks for trying to help either way!

Answer (score 0):

heyy, you can fork your repl, if you're token is in the process.env you must add it, else if your token is in a config.json file, it's ok, just fork it and it's done

Comment: Im new to this and don't really know what are you saying but I found a way to fix the problem. Thanks for trying to help!